# Complex integral! Am I doing it correctly?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to calculate the integral 
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^{2}+2z} $$

From what I've understood I can replace the $z$ with $e^{it}$.
So I have:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{e^{it2}+2e^{it}}ie^{it}dt $$

And now I compute it as a normal integral?

Comment: Yes. This is a correct method. It is using the definition.

Comment: Thank you for helping!

Comment: You might want to do a partial fraction decomposition before you do the substitution.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{z^2+2z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z+2}\right)$

Comment: Have you learned the Residue Theorem?

Comment: I have not, learned the residue theorem yet. Very new to complex analysis :)